# Verify if an abstract method is called using moq

Tags: c#, moq

I have created an abstract baseclass with some abstract methods:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T: class, IEntity
{

  public T Load(long id)
  {
     //if in cache continue with cached value 
     //else make use of protected abstract LoadFromContext
  }

  protected abstract T LoadFromContext(long id);
}
```

now I want to check if the LoadFromContext us called but I get an error : *System.ArgumentException: Member FakeCacheRepository.LoadFromContext does not exist*

**Unittest Moq Setup where FakeCacheRepository is a derived type of MyBaseClass:**

```
Mock<FakeCacheRepository> personRepoMock = new Mock<FakeCacheRepository>();
personRepoMock.Setup(x => x.Load(14)).Returns(new Person() { ID = 14, Name = "Developer14" });
personRepoMock.Protected().Setup("LoadFromContext");

var person = new FakeCacheRepository().Load(14);

Assert.AreEqual("Developer14", person.Name);
personRepoMock.Protected().Verify("LoadFromContext", Times.Once());
```

What an I doing wrong and are there any good tutorials about moq for a better understanding without having to Google each individual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mock object `personRepoMock` that you setup doesn't appear to be being used by the `FakeCacheRepository` object `person`. So your setup and verify aren't used.

However, I don't think that this is the correct approach for testing this, I would just test the `FakeCacheRepository` class without mocking. Externally, it shouldn't matter that `FakeCacheRepository` inherits from `MyBaseClass`, so just test the methods that `FakeCacheRepository` exposes.

If you want to share code between multiple classes, extract that code into a separate class - inheritance shouldn't be used for sharing code.

Comment: Hi Tom, without wanting to start a discussion over here how code should be build. Where can i find guidelines when code should be inherited en when code should be extracted. The baseclass discussed here has officially the name "CachedRepositoryBase"...all the cache stuff is placed in here. Only Connection specific stuff is placed in the inherited classes what still are cached repository classes (so inheritance). This seemed legit for me at the moment.

Comment: I don't have any specific links to send, but a quick Google of the phrase "writing testable code" brought up quite a few articles that might be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what TomDoesCode already said:

To use `Protected()` the way you do, you'll have to use the generic version, since `LoadFromContext` returns a value (`Person`). Also, you'll have to pass the parameter:

```
personRepoMock.Protected().Setup<Person>("LoadFromContext", 14L);
```

Likewise, your `Verify` has to look like

```
personRepoMock.Protected().Verify<Person>("LoadFromContext", Times.Once(), 14L);
```

But even if you would change that, your test would not work. You create a mock of `FakeCacheRepository`, but then call `Load(14)` on a new instance of  `FakeCacheRepository`, not on the mock.

You should take a step back and think about what exactly you want to test. If you want to test if `FakeCacheRepository` calls `LoadFromContext` from `Load`, then moq is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: What other options for testing if "LoadFromContext"  is called from Load do I have? Other than Debugging by hand. I'm new to unit testing but i see the possibilities and advantages. Don't want to stop already while knowing that testing is the right way to go.

Comment: If you really want to test that, you could create a subclass of `MyBaseClass` that simply sets a flag in `LoadFromContext`, and after calling `Load` check if that flag is set with a simply `Assert`. If you now abstract away the caching you wrote about in your code, you could also test if `LoadFromContext` is *not* called in case the cache is used.